# Shadow mapping not working on OpenGL 3.3, but working on 4.4

Tags: opengl, shadow

I have my shadow mapping tecnique running fine in my OpenGL application, with my latest 4.4 core profile drivers, however, I'm following the 3.3 specification, that should allow me to run in inferior hardware, with the same graphical result, but it doesn't.

My shadows are not appearing on  OpenGL 3.3 hardware, and besides that, the performance is incredibly low, I even run my application on the same graphic card, but with only one version older driver (4.2), and my shadow didn't appear.

The weird thing also, is that before the last actualization, there weren't any of these problems.

I have a Radeon HD 6870 with the latest omega drivers, do I need to compile my application with older drivers versions in order to target old hardware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that you actually get a valid GPU accelerated OpenGL context of the required version. You may unknowingly request a profile that your driver doesn't properly support and drop to some emulation mode. Check the strings GL_RENDERER and GL_VENDOR and the OpenGL version of your context.

> do I need to compile my application with older drivers versions in order to target old hardware?

Certainly not.

Comment: You are right, the GL_RENDERER string returns a null value, and whenever I try to force Accelerated Rendering, I get a black screen.

Comment: Could this be related to SDL2?

Comment: You were Right!
I just replaced SDL2 with glfw, and the problem is gone, and even more, I have even more FPS in my working machine!